# Amazon Instance Got Terminated frequently

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, instance, aws-cli

We have basic plan Amazon configuration. Also we have created Windows instance which is terminated frequently and new Ip address is assigned. I don't know how to check and why its terminated frequently.

Comment: Are you using spot requests?

Comment: do you enable auto-scaling services?

Comment: Auto scaling means. I am new to Amazon

Answer (score 0):

Under standard conditions, Amazon EC2 instances are never terminated on their own. You may be accidentally using EC2 Spot instances which works on a bidding model. AWS has the power to terminate these instances with a warning time of ~2 minutes if there is a a higher bid for the spot instance.

If your instances get terminated immediately after you launch, refer this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_InstanceStraightToTerminated.html

For more information on EC2 spot instances, refer this page:
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/spot-instances/